# MadExcept triggers on try finally

Tags: delphi, madexcept

I am using MadExcept to debug my applications. It's an excelent framework though when a exception ocurrs on a try finally block it still displays that ugly box and the user thinks the app has crashed.

How can i remove that ? Is there a way ?

Comment: Take madExcept out and see what happens. Yup, you've still got and unhandled exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like it's working as designed.  A try/finally block does not catch exceptions; it ensures that proper cleanup can be done even if an exception is raised.

If you want to handle an exception, you need to use a try/except block instead.